# Mvc SelectList doesn't bind if Dictionary key is nullable decimal

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Why is my dropdownlist not binding? Using the DropDownListFor Razor helper function.

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ModelObject.VatRate, Model.VatRatesList)
```

ViewModel:

```
    public SelectList VatRatesList
    {
        get
        {
            return new SelectList(
                new Dictionary<decimal, string>
                {
                    { 0m, string.Empty },
                    { 1.2m, "20%" },
                    { 1m, "0%" }
                }, "Key", "Value",
                ModelObject.VatRate ?? 0m);
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Paste the code for  your `ModelObject`?

Comment: And also your view code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

On further investigation I have found out that this is something to do with the model property that I am trying to bind. It is a nullable decimal. When I change it to a decimal, the correct value is selected from the list.

Here is where things start to  get weird. If I use 4 decimal places for the dictionary keys, it works with a nullable decimal model property. In other words, this works:

```
 public SelectList VatRatesList
    {
        get
        {
            return new SelectList(
                new Dictionary<decimal, string>
                {
                    { 0.0000m, string.Empty },
                    { 1.2000m, "20%"},
                    { 1.0000m, "0%"}
                }, "Key", "Value");
        }
    }
```

I have no idea why. Perhaps html helper uses ToString() internally. I think ToString() would give a 4dp string representation of the decimal. I'll have to look at the MVC source code to find out.

Answer (score 1):

That **exact** code works for me (can't see the rest of your model/view so it's fairly difficult to ascertain the problem). This is the code that I used:

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
        var model = new Model();
        model.ModelObject = new ModelObject();

        model.ModelObject.VatRatesList = new SelectList(
            new Dictionary<decimal, string>
            {
                { 0m, string.Empty },
                { 1.2m, "20%" },
                { 1m, "0%" }
            }, "Key", "Value",
            model.ModelObject.VatRate ?? 0m);

        return View(model);
 }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ModelObject.VatRate, Model.ModelObject.VatRatesList)
<input type="submit" value="Submit me"/>
}
```

Controller Post Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Model model)
{
    //Breakpointing on the below line, I can see model.ModelObject.VatRate
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I used these two classes:

```
public class Model
{
    public ModelObject ModelObject { get; set; }
}

public class ModelObject
{
    public decimal? VatRate { get; set; }
    public SelectList VatRatesList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does it select "20%" if you set ModelObject.VatRate to 1.2?

Comment: Ah you mean in the view? Yeah it preselects 20% if I set the VatRate to 1.2m. Does it not for you?

Comment: No it doesn't, even though I can see it's 1.2m when i put a breakpoint in the get.

Comment: Does your code **exactly** match mine? Can you paste it **ALL**?

Comment: Haven't solved this yet, and moved onto something else, but you get the correct answer by default I guess. Will come back to this in maybe next week.